# PIL Image.fromstring from PyOpengl buffer has the wrong size

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, glut, pyopengl

I use PyOpenGL to draw a 2D Image. Then I want to use the Python Imaging Library (PIL) to store this image to disk. I use GLUT to display the image which works perfectly. But when I use PIL to store the image it extracts the wrong clipping. It has the wrong size.

Here is a minimal example which reproduces the effect and I also attach the output to make it more clear without running some code.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from PIL import Image

width, height = 640, 480

def DrawStuff():
    poly1 = [(0,0), (640,0), (0,480)]
    color = (0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.8)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glPushMatrix()
    glLineWidth(5.0)

    glColor4f(*color)
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(poly1[0][0], poly1[0][1])
    glVertex2f(poly1[1][0], poly1[1][1])
    glVertex2f(poly1[2][0], poly1[2][1])    
    glVertex2f(poly1[0][0], poly1[0][1])
    glEnd() # GL_POLYGON

    glPopMatrix()
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
    data = glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
    image = Image.fromstring("RGBA", (width, height), data)
    image.show()
    image.save('out.png', 'PNG')
    glutSwapBuffers()


# glut initialization
glutInit(sys.argv)
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA)
glutCreateWindow("Draw Polygons")
glutInitWindowSize(width, height)

# set the function to draw
glutDisplayFunc(DrawStuff)

# enable the alpha blending
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

# prepare for 2D drawing
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 0, 1)
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

# start the mainloop
glutMainLoop ()
```

[image: this is how it looks int the GLUT window and how it is supposed to look like]
this is how it looks int the GLUT window and how it is supposed to look like

[image: and this is how the saved image looks like]
and this is how the saved image looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my own Problem.

First I tried the following solution which might also help people with related problems:
[solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378297/trying-to-graph-a-simple-square-in-pyopengl)

But then, through extensive trial and error, I found that the solution is much simpler.

I simply had to swap two lines from:

```
glutCreateWindow("Draw Polygons")
glutInitWindowSize(width, height)
```

to

```
glutInitWindowSize(width, height)
glutCreateWindow("Draw Polygons")
```

Apparently the size has to be set before the window

Answer (score 0):

You should consider that in OpenGL the coordinate system starts at different place than in PIL. Look at [this](http://blog.jayway.com/2010/01/01/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-%E2%80%93-part-iii-%E2%80%93-transformations/).

Comment: thanks for sour help. But his was not the problem. I found the solution but cannot post it as an answer because I don't have enough reputation. I'll edit the question.

Comment: This is a shining example of why answers shouldn't rely on links to explain.  Note the dead link.  It's a shame as the question (and potentially this answer) are still relevant.